# Execute code on object passed in as parameter to mocked static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write unit tests for a class which is using a static method in another class to make HTTP calls. When the static class method is executed it updates one of the objects which is being passed in as a parameter with the response from the API it is calling.  In the example below it updates the HTTPResponseHolder with a status code and a response body.

```
final HTTPResponseHolder responseHolder = new HTTPResponseHolder();
HttpUtil.doPost("http://authEndpoint", bodyEncoded, headers, responseHolder);
```

I am trying to mock this in a unit test. Is there a way using PowerMock, or really any testing framework in which I can have a block of code executed when the mocked static method is called?  Specifically something like the code shown below.

```
final String authResponse = "{\"access_token\": \"authToken\",\"expires_in\": 3600,\"token_type\": \"Bearer\"";
responseHolderOutput.setResponse(authResponse)
```

Comment: Personally, I've come to not like PowerMock as it usually makes it too easy to allow poor design.  Is there a legitimate reason why that `HttpUtil` method is static?  Why does it take in the object and make a side-effect, instead of returning the object?  If you have no choice but to use `HttpUtil` as is, consider creating an `HttpUtilWrapper` that can be instantiated.  Its methods would just delegate to the static methods.  But for unit testing, the wrapper class can be mocked.

Comment: hey check this paste, i am assuming certain things that you doPost methods does let me know if that is correct, let me know more details so that we will fix your test
https://pastebin.com/wgSA0Qpr